# How to create programmatically a toolbar that will fill all the bottom space in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, toolbar

How can I force the toolbar to fill all bottom space? Because, as you can see, right now toolbar only took a small line, and the space under the toolbar is empty.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

class AllChecklistsT1: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let b1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 1", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        let b2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 2", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        
        self.toolbarItems = [b1, spaceButton, b2]
        
        self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        
        self.navigationController?.toolbar.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .darkGray

    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need a toolbar or a tab bar?

Comment: I need to add the toolbar

Comment: Consider creating a custom `UIView` subclass and constraining it to the bottom of the view controller's view.

Comment: Looks like you are in a Navigation Controller that is one of your Tab controllers. Take a look at this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-hide-the-tab-bar-when-a-view-controller-is-shown

Comment: @DonMag thanks. Working well!